# Story about a spacecraft that crash-lands on a planet with a civilization resembling Pre-Columbian era

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, technology, soft-sci-fi

I have read this book around 20 years ago, and the book was already quite old at that time so was likely written before 1990. Highly likely I have read it in Hungarian, but I'm unsure if the novel was a translation or from a Hungarian author. It was a quite long novel, I think more than 250-300 pages, and if I remember correctly it was part of a series, as it starts by describing events of the previous book.

Here is how the story goes:

- A spacecraft crash lands on an alien planet. There is only one survivor who is the protagonist (this happens in the previous book)
- The aliens are human-like and have a medieval technology level, more specifically it was like the technology level of pre-Columbian native Americans (this becomes important later).
- The protagonist is looked at as a God, and becomes the ruler of one of the nations.
- Nations are not too friendly with each other, there are both wars, and more peaceful times where trade is present.
- He tries to introduce new technology into the world. For example as the nation is abundant with silica, one of the technological advancement he tries to do is teaching people how to make glass objects.
- He intends glass objects to be used as a cheap alternative to current everyday items (like bottles and glasses), however when one shatters people start to use them as jewelry, and it actually becomes an expensive major trade item between the nations.
- Other nations are getting envious of glass jewelries and try to figure out how they are made - however they both lack the knowledge and the resources needed to make glass. There are a couple sections around spies trying to steal the technology for example.
- Towards the end of the book a scout finds an unknown sunken ship near the coast. The protagonist investigates the ship and realizes they are from a technologically much more advanced nation. He deduces this as the ship contained well made iron screws, which was not something that was feasible with the current technology level of where he was - ironmongery was not advanced enough to produce items like that.
- I believe he did try to rally all the local nations together as he expected invaders to come from the sea and not be friendly. In the end the invaders did arrive, and as expected they were technologically much more advanced - around 15th century Europe technology level.

Can't really remember how the story ended. I vaguely remember that the people and the nations were taken over by the invaders the same way Columbus and the rest of the expeditions around that time have taken over the Americas. I think there were some other hints throughout the novel that the place he landed was actually Earth in the past.

Comment: Not "Defilers of the Golden Empire", right? there isn't a sunken ship or uplifting a civilization.